# Unable to redirect to MainActivity screen

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, eclipse

I am just a newbie and I have build up my application to start with a layout named user_login.xml. When I click on the login button, however it is unable to redirect me to the activity_main.xml. The json should works fine. What should I do in order to solve this? Sorry if I used wrong words to explain my problem. Thanks in advance. Here is the Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alan.smarthome"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

    <application
        android:name="com.alan.smarthome.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.alan.smarthome.UserLogin"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                  android:label="Register New Account"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the UserLogin.java that I have created

```
package com.alan.smarthome;


import com.alan.smarthome.app.AppConfig;
import com.alan.smarthome.app.AppController;
import com.alan.smarthome.helper.SessionManager;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;


public class UserLogin extends Activity {

        // LogCat tag
        private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private Button btnLogin;
        private TextView btnLinkToRegister;
        private EditText inputUsername;
        private EditText inputPassword;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private SessionManager session;
        /*
        private TextView attempts;
        int counter = 3; */ 

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.user_login);


                inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnUsername);
                inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnPassword);
                btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
                btnLinkToRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

                // Progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);

                // Session manager
                session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

                // Check if user is already logged in or not
                if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
                    // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(UserLogin.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }


          // Login button Click Event
          btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                        String name = inputUsername.getText().toString();
                        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                        // Check for empty data in the form
                        if (name.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                            // login user
                            checkLogin(name, password);
                        } else {
                            // Prompt user to enter credentials
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                }
          });

          // Link to Register Screen
          btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });

        }


        /**
         * function to verify login details in mysql db
         * */
        private void checkLogin(final String name, final String password) {
            // Tag used to cancel the request
            String tag_string_req = "req_login";

            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            showDialog();

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                    AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                            hideDialog();

                            try {
                                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                                // Check for error node in json
                                if (!error) {
                                    // user successfully logged in
                                    // Create login session
                                    session.setLogin(true);

                                    // Launch main activity                     
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(UserLogin.this,
                                                    MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // JSON error
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            hideDialog();
                        }
                    }) {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            // Posting parameters to login url
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("tag", "login");
                            params.put("name", name);
                            params.put("password", password);

                            return params;
                        }

                    };

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
        }

        private void showDialog() {
            if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.show();
        }

        private void hideDialog() {
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

And this is the error I get from LogCat when I try to login to the activity_main.xml

```
03-09 16:53:13.975: W/System.err(783): org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after main at character 6 of {main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
03-09 16:53:13.975: W/System.err(783): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>279456</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Functions->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>19</td></tr>
03-09 16:53:13.975: W/System.err(783): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0020</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>285592</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Connect->connect(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\DB_Functions.php<b>:</b>13</td></tr>
03-09 16:53:13.985: W/System.err(783): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0020</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>286432</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect</a>
03-09 16:53:13.985: W/System.err(783): (  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Connect.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\DB_Connect.php<b>:</b>18</td></tr>
03-09 16:53:13.985: W/System.err(783): </table></font>
03-09 16:53:13.985: W/System.err(783): {"tag":"login","error":false,"uid":"54fdd87267a3f5.49630793","user":{"name":"Alan","email":"alan@hotmail.com","created_at":"2015-03-10 01:29:22","updated_at":null}}
03-09 16:53:13.985: W/System.err(783):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
03-09 16:53:13.985: W/System.err(783):  at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:379)
03-09 16:53:13.985: W/System.err(783):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at com.alan.smarthome.UserLogin$3.onResponse(UserLogin.java:129)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at com.alan.smarthome.UserLogin$3.onResponse(UserLogin.java:1)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-09 16:53:13.995: W/System.err(783):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And the php files:

DB_Connect.php

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

        // return database handler
        return $con;
    }

    // Closing database connection
    public function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

config.php

```
<?php

    /**
     * Database config variables
     */
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "android_api");
    ?>
```

DB_Functions.php

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by name and password
     */
    public function getUserByNameAndPassword($name, $password) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $salt = $result['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($name) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT name from users WHERE name = '$name'");
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

Index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * File to handle all API requests
 * Accepts GET and POST
 * Each request will be identified by TAG
 * Response will be JSON data

  /**
 * check for POST request 
 */
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByNameAndPassword($name, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect name or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check if user is already existed
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registration";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknow 'tag' value. It should be either 'login' or 'register'";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please include the json format that you are trying to parse the response.

Comment: @icaneatclouds Sorry, I am still confuse on finding the json format...what should I do to in order show the json format?

Answer (score 0):

> org.json.JSONException: Expected ':'after main at character 6 of...

Clearly you are not receiving a valid JSON response (it looks like HTML).

This part:

> 03-09 16:53:13.985: W/System.err(783): 40.0020286432http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect'
>   target='_new'>mysql_connect 03-09 16:53:13.985: W/System.err(783):
>   (  )..\DB_Connect.php**:**18

Suggest that you need to fix errors in your PHP script, also you should log the error, and if you need to send it in json format

Comment: I have checked the php script but I still can't find any error...I have uploaded the php files in above.

Comment: show how you use the class and explain why is there HTML in the response, it should be json only

Comment: I have a php file named DB_Funtions to allow the user register and create an account, and then login via username and password. Meanwhile my index.php will accepts GET and POST and response in JSON data. Again I have uploaded these two files. The problem should be from these two files but I still cant figure it out. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check first the API backend of your app for some errors.

To parse complex Json hierarchies. Try to use this library: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Sample Usage:

**Create first an object where you want to insert the json string. Note: the variable names should match your json tags, or you should put @SerializedName("firstname"); at the beginning of a variable.**

```
public class UserDto implements Serializable {

    private long _id;
    private String id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String emp_code;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String usertype;


    public long get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(long _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setUserId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getEmp_code() {
        return emp_code;
    }

    public void setEmp_code(String emp_code) {
        this.emp_code = emp_code;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsertype() {
        return usertype;
    }

    public void setUsertype(String usertype) {
        this.usertype = usertype;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }  
}
```

**Here's How to parse the JSON String:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
UserDto userDto= gson.fromJson(stringJsonHere, UserDto.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your web server setting for php. PHP error reporting turn your index.php to html instead json.

1. Edit your php.ini and set error_reporting settings. Set it off
2. If you use .htaccess file, insert php_flag display_errors 0
3. You can add `error_reporting(0)` on top of index.php

Please also check your mysql php settings in web server. Error report show that it was triggered by mysql_connect().

Answer (score 0):

Your response string is json itself.
Try showning response string in logcat.
Instead of this:

```
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

Try this:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

Comment: I was using this at first, but it gave me error like this: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.